# How get int from node.js buffer

Tags: node.js

is the code:

```
var time = new Buffer('506BF1E3','hex');
time.toString() //'Pk��'
```

0x506BF1E3 = 1349251555 unixtime;

How get '1349251555' form `time` Buffer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one will do the trick as well. Convert hex to int by calling parseInt with radix argument 16:

```
var time = new Buffer('506BF1E3','hex');
console.log(parseInt(time.toString('hex'), 16));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this? Seems much better than parsing...

```
time.readUInt32BE(0)
```

However, I think you need to make sure that this is always 4 bytes (32-bits), otherwise it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick:

```
var time = new Buffer('506BF1E3','hex');
console.log(parseInt("0x"+time.toString("hex")));
```