# Buffer Logical And

Tags: node.js

I have a hex string that needs to be converted to a buffer and have its bits checked. However, when I do a logical AND, it doesn't seem to give me a proper output:

```js
const text = 'FF8134'

const buff = new Buffer.from(text.substring(2, 4), 'hex')
console.log('buff in string: ' + buff.toString('hex'))

if ((buff & 0x80) === 0x80) {
  console.log('B2b8 is set')
} else {
  console.log('B2b8 is NOT set')
}
```

The output is:

```
buff in string: 81
B2b8 is NOT set
```

In this example, my buff is `0x81`. I do not understand why this line is not being satisfied:

```
(buff & 0x80) === 0x80
```

This is very simple but I just don't understand why this isn't working, what am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that a `Buffer` object is not an integer.
It is an object that can contain an integer, but it is not an integer itself.

For example, if you run

```js
const text = 'FF8134'

const buff = new Buffer.from(text.substring(2, 4), 'hex')

console.log(buff)
console.log(0x81)
```

You get

```
<Buffer 81>
129
```

You need to convert the `Buffer` to some integer type.

There are numerous functions available, but selecting the appropriate one depends on factors such as whether it is signed or unsigned, the length of bytes it uses, and the encoding it employs (big-endian or little-endian).

- buf.readInt8([offset])
- buf.readInt16BE([offset])
- buf.readInt16LE([offset])
- buf.readInt32BE([offset])
- buf.readInt32LE([offset])
- buf.readIntBE(offset, byteLength)
- buf.readIntLE(offset, byteLength)
- buf.readUInt8([offset])
- buf.readUInt16BE([offset])
- buf.readUInt16LE([offset])
- buf.readUInt32BE([offset])
- buf.readUInt32LE([offset])
- buf.readUIntBE(offset, byteLength)
- buf.readUIntLE(offset, byteLength)

See https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

For example, assuming in your case that it is always non-negative and uses 8 bits (1 byte), you can use `readUInt8()` method.

```js
if ((buff.readUInt8() & 0x80) === 0x80) {
  console.log('B2b8 is set')
} else {
  console.log('B2b8 is NOT set')
}
```

Or alternatively, you can use the `parseInt()` function and the `toString()` method of `Buffer`.
You can search how to convert or parse nodejs `Buffer` to integer in Google if you want to use another method like [How get int from node.js buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504632/how-get-int-from-node-js-buffer).

Also, as a side note, `&` is called the bitwise AND operator, not the logical AND operator (which is `&&`).